# Eclipse: UTF-8 encoding not shown correctly in Texlipse editor

Tags: eclipse, encoding, tex

I'm working on a LaTeX project in Eclipse with German text. On one of our project computers, the words with Umlauts are shown with the wrong encoding, e.g.:

```
Ãbersicht Ã¼ber
```

rather than:

```
Übersicht über
```

Under Window --> Preferences --> General --> Workspace the text file encoding is set to `"Default (UTF-8)"`. Also, I have the following line at the top of the TeX file:

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

Here's the output of `locale`:

```
me@localhost:~> locale
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Here are the TeXlipse settings:

```
#TeXlipse project settings
#Tue Apr 29 11:10:19 CEST 2014
markTmpDer=true
builderNum=2
outputDir=
makeIndSty=
bibrefDir=
outputFormat=pdf
tempDir=tmp
mainTexFile=main.tex
outputFile=out.pdf
langSpell=de
markDer=true
srcDir=
```

On the other computers it works fine. If I open the file in another editor (e.g. Kile, vi, etc.) the umlauts are also shown correctly. What's the problem here?

Comment: btw. Umlaute -> special charaters

Comment: Have you checked the project settings? These overwrite the general settings.

Comment: @reporter I just posted them. My ``.project`` file looks fine, it doesn't seem to contain anything pertaining to text encoding. Nor can I find anything in ``.texlipse``.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and could resolve by accessing "Project properties > Resource" and, in the groupbox "Text file enconding", selecting "Other (UTF-8)", instead of "Inherited from container" (whose value was "Cp1252").